# Can I install devDependencies only for the install step in an NPM package?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I have an NPM package that lives on GitHub. Since it uses modern ES, I am transpiling it down as part of the `install` script:

```
...
"license": "MIT",
"scripts": {
  "install": "mkdir -p lib && babel src/index.js -o lib/index.js",
  "test": "jest src"
},
"dependencies": {
...
```

This requires Babel, which is in `devDependencies`:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "@babel/cli": "^7.0.0-beta.37",
  "@babel/core": "^7.0.0-beta.37",
  "@babel/node": "^7.0.0-beta.37",
  "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0-beta.37"
}
```

Babel is not required to use the package, only to build it.

However, NPM does not install the `devDependencies` when running the `install` script. This causes `install` to fail:

```
$ npm install git+ssh://git@github.com:user/repo.git 
Error: Couldn't find preset "@babel/preset-env" relative to directory 
"/Users/User/Documents/js/test/node_modules/mylib"
...
```

I could move the `devDependencies` in `dependencies`, but this bloats the package.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: You should deliver the compiled `lib/index.js` as part of your npm package instead of trying to build it on install.

Comment: @RaphaelSchweikert I want to keep everything on GitHub. Tracking a compiled file in source-control is not ideal.

Comment: "when running the install script" what does this script look like?

Comment: @Liam install script is in question

Comment: You don’t have to commit the lib folder to git, you just have to make sure it is included when doing `npm publish`. The install step is only meant for doing processing based on the installer’s environment, not for computations you could do before-hand.

Comment: @RaphaelSchweikert I am not using NPM for data storage. I am not running `npm publish`.

Comment: The ability to install from git is suboptimal in this regard because it requires the distribution package to be checked into git. Either use a real npm registry or live with the inconvenience of having dist files in git. That’s why it isn’t common to publish npm packages only to git. In fact, most published npm packages will not work when installed from their repositories instead of the npm registry.